# Moq: How to mock method with `complex type` parameter

Tags: c#, moq

Original title:

> Moq: Mocking method method with `out parameter` returns empty array

The problem was not with the `out parameter` but with the `complex type parameter` `albumFilters` of `complex type` `AlbumFilter`.  See my Answer for details.

I have Moq working for a method without an `out parameter` but when I try and Moq with an `out parameter` it returns an empty array.

The `GetAllAlbums_ok_returnsdata_test()` passes. The `GetAllAlbumsPaged_test()` fails. The call to the `_inventoryService` in the `GetAllAlbumsPaged` method in the `AlbumApiController` returns an empty array `Album[]`.

I've looked at the [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) section on using `out arguments`.

> // out arguments
>
> var outString = "ack";
>
> // TryParse will return true, and the out argument will return "ack",
>   lazy evaluated
>
> mock.Setup(foo => foo.TryParse("ping", out outString)).Returns(true);

**Test Class:**

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllAlbums_ok_returnsdata_test() {
  Mock<IInventoryService> mockInventoryService
                      = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
  Album[] albums = { new Album { AlbumId = 1 },
    new Album { AlbumId = 2 } };
  mockInventoryService.Setup(obj => obj.GetAllAlbums()).Returns(albums);

  AlbumApiController controller = new AlbumApiController(mockInventoryService.Object);

  IHttpActionResult response = controller.GetAllAlbums();
  var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Album[]>;
  Assert.NotNull(contentResult);
  Assert.NotNull(contentResult.Content);
  var data = contentResult.Content;
  Assert.Equal(data, albums); }

[Fact]
public void GetAllAlbumsPaged_test() {
  Mock<IInventoryService> mockInventoryService
                      = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
  Album[] albums = new Album[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) albums[i] = new Album { AlbumId = i + 1 };
  var albumFilter = new AlbumFilter { AlbumNumber = "", Artist = "",
      Title = "", Genre = 0, Price = 0, StockAmount = 0 };
  var sortItems = new List<SortItem>(); 
  int totalCount;

  mockInventoryService.Setup(obj => obj.GetAllAlbumsPaged(out totalCount, albumFilter,
        sortItems, 0, 4)).Returns(albums);

  AlbumApiController controller = new AlbumApiController(mockInventoryService.Object);

  IHttpActionResult response = controller.GetAllAlbumsPaged(Json.Encode(albumFilter),
        Json.Encode(sortItems), 0, 4);
  var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<object>;
  Assert.NotNull(contentResult); }
```

**AlbumApiController:**

```
public class AlbumApiController : ApiController
  {
    private readonly IInventoryService _inventoryService;

    public AlbumApiController(IInventoryService inventoryService)
    { _inventoryService = inventoryService; }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getallalbums")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllAlbums() {
      return GetHttpResponse(Request, () => {
        var albums = _inventoryService.GetAllAlbums();
        return Ok(albums); }); }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getallalbumspaged/{pageIndex}/{pageSize}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllAlbumsPaged(string filters, string sorts,
          int pageIndex, int pageSize) { 
      var _filters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlbumFilter>(filters);
      var _sorts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SortItem>>(sorts);
      return GetHttpResponse(Request, () => {
        int totalCount;
        var albums = _inventoryService.GetAllAlbumsPaged(out totalCount, _filters,
          _sorts, pageIndex, pageSize);
        var albums_Count = new { albums, totalCount };
        return Ok(albums_Count); }); } }
```

**Update:**

I added this test method to the `AlbumAPIController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetTest(int intTest)
{
  return GetHttpResponse(Request, () => {
    int testInt;
    var albums = _inventoryService.GetTest(out testInt, intTest);
    return Ok(albums);
  });
}
```

and this test to the test class:

```
[Fact]
public void GetTest_test() {
  Mock<IInventoryService> mockInventoryService
                = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
  Album[] albums = new Album[20];
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) albums[i] = new Album { AlbumId = i + 1 };
  int testInt = 15;
  mockInventoryService.Setup(obj => obj.GetTest(out testInt, 5)).Returns(albums);

  AlbumApiController controller = new AlbumApiController(mockInventoryService.Object);
  IHttpActionResult response = controller.GetTest(5);
  var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Album[]>;

  Assert.NotNull(contentResult);
  Assert.NotNull(contentResult.Content);
  var data = contentResult.Content;
  Assert.Equal(data, albums); }
```

The test passed and the testInt was updated in the `GetTest` method so the problem doesn't seem to be with the 'out parameter`.

Per Diana's troubleshooting suggestion I added this to the `GetAllAlbumsPaged` method (right after the `JsonConverts`) to ensure the issue wasn't with the `JSON`.

```
  _filters = new AlbumFilter { AlbumNumber = "", Artist = "",
      Title = "", Genre = 0, Price = 0, StockAmount = 0 };
  _sorts = new List<SortItem>();
```

The call to the `_inventoryService.GetAllAlbumsPaged` method still returns an empty array, `Albums[]`.

Comment: The issue might not be in the out parameter but in the other parameters, `albumFilter` and `sortItems`. To confirm that, remove temporarily the out parameter from your method and check if the test still fails. In that case, check if `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlbumFilter>(Json.Encode(albumFilter))` is exactly equal to your `albumFilter`variable. Do the same for `sortItems`. I suspect that the mocked method is not being invoked because the parameter values don't match.

Comment: @Diana good troubleshooting suggestion.  Didn't fix it though.  See Update inOP.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `out parameter` was not the problem.  The `complex type` parameter `AlbumFilter` was the problem.  `Moq` apparently didn't like the `complex type`.  I was able to get it to work by changing the `mockInventoryService` setup by passing `It.IsAny<AlbumFilter>()` instead of the instance of the `AlbumFilter`, `albumFilter`.

```
 mockInventoryService.Setup(obj => obj.GetAllAlbumsPaged(out totalCount,
                      It.IsAny<AlbumFilter>(), sortItems, 0, 4)).Returns(albums);
```